# How to write unit tests with parameters?

Tags: java, c#, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I am not familiar to java but in c#(NUnit) you can parameterize unit tests by adding `[TestCase]` attribute as following:

```
[TestCase(12,3,4)]
[TestCase(12,2,6)]
[TestCase(12,4,3)]
public void DivideTest(int n, int d, int q)
{
   Assert.AreEqual( q, n / d );
}
```

In this case we do not have to write seperate unit test for every test case. Instead we have writing [TestCase] to change the value.

Are there any equivelant on Java?
Currently using `Junit 4.12`

Comment: Take a look at parameterized tests (https://www.tutorialspoint.com/junit/junit_parameterized_test.htm). Take note of the constructor - you can specify how many args the method can take. Not as pretty (and maybe not as good) in Java but this would be one option and you can reuse the same test case for different test data

Comment: @robjob27 , I looked the link you provided. But it is not looking nice like nunit. Does it possible to make it look like more elegant. By elegant i mean simplified like nunit. Or at least, do I have any option to write new attribute for it and convert it into JUnit style in behind?

Comment: @AkinerAlkan Yeah, I agree. These do not look pretty at all. As a side note, one thing in C# that are really cool are theories. Basically like the test cases above but it abstracts it further.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Parameterized is what you need. Consider the below example. Note that test3 is obviously RED as 20/5 = 4.

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runners.Parameterized;

@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
public class DividerTest {

  private int dividend;
  private int divisor;
  private int expectedResult;

  @Parameterized.Parameters
  public static Collection<Object[]> data() {
    Object[] test1 = { 10, 5, 2 };
    Object[] test2 = { 15, 5, 3 };
    Object[] test3 = { 20, 5, 5 };

    return Arrays.asList(test1, test2, test3);
  }

  public DividerTest(int dividend, int divisor, int expectedResult) {
    this.dividend = dividend;
    this.divisor = divisor;
    this.expectedResult = expectedResult;
  }

  @Test
  public void testDivider() {
    assertEquals(expectedResult, dividend / divisor);
  }
}
```

And here are the test results:

[image]

Comment: This is a good example and I understand that this is the same logic with nunit but different represantion. What I wonder is: Can we write some kind of generic code and simplify the collection creation such like in nunit scenario. Then in that case we can have the exact same implementation like [TestCase(x,y,z)]

Comment: As of now, I think Junit doesnt support [TestCase(x,y,z)]. So the answer is not yet :)

Comment: Not yet, but there is better parametrized support coming in JUnit5. Perhaps not as elegant, but its close. Check out @CsvSource:

http://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-parameterized-tests

Answer (score 0):

TestNG is a library and framework with excellent control over test parameters using data factories and dependency injection.